Optionally producing a message using a Function<> in spring cloud stream
Is there a way to only optionally produce a message from a spring cloud stream Function<> that has been registered with both an in and out bindings? Currently, the method signature expects you to return a produced message type all the time.
I did try refactoring it as a Consumer<> spring cloud method and using StreamBridge to send a message from the Consumer<>. But, this creates a circular reference exception with StreamBridge preventing the use of StreamBridge inside Consumer<> methods

Doesn't just return null; from the Function work?

Exactly what Artem said
